# Running up a custom method as a Thread

Tags: c#, java, multithreading, comparison

In Java to run a separate thread we have to implement Runnable interface or extend Thread class, so in effect only the method Run() can be used to start up a new thread.

In C# we can call up any method to run up as a new thread using 
new Thread(target function);

so in effect in Java we end up creating a separate class for a function to be able to run as a Thread.
So is there a way to avoid that ?

I want to avoid any changes in the architecture and the method itself isn't very lengthy, its just two loops which are time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my Java knowledge goes: the only way to run a thread is to call run() via any of the supplied ways such as the ones you named.

You can however just put a call to your method inside the run. Then you don't change much of your architecture as well.

Answer (score 3):

While not perfect, you can use an anonymous inner class to wrap your function. The code to execute your function on a separate thread would look something like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread () {
     public void run()
     {
        myMethodHere();
     }

};

t.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

In java a function (or even better method) is not an object itself and thus you'll have to create such a wrapper to perform what you want.

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        originalMethod();
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper method which uses reflection to implement

```
backgroundMethod("methodName");
```

or

```
backgroundMethod(object, "methodName");
```

Unless this is something you do often, using the Runnable suggested by others may be better/clearer.